# Whitening Transformation with Autoregressive Model

Tags: data-transformation, autoregressive, arma

I am new to the topic of whitening transformation. In financial time series studies on long memory in data, I have seen that researchers apply an AR(p) model to detrended return series in order to retrieve "white" residuals (white noise residuals). The whitening (or pre-whitening) is done a single detrended return series with stationary increments.

The common whitening methods are: Mahalanobis or ZCA whitening, Cholesky whitening and PCA whitening.

1. Which whitening method describes the approach mentioned above (using an AR(p) model)?
2. Secondly, in case the method above is PCA whitening. What is the link between between PCA analysis and AR(p) model? Is there a link between coefficients in the AR model and PCA?